# Restrict user to download doc, docx, xlx file from browser but can view

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee, liferay-6, liferay-aui

We have one requirement to restrict download for mentioned extension doc, docx, and xls. User can only view this file but can not download from browser.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: and how do you expect the user to "view" that content without the file being downloaded?

Comment: Is your question about Javascript or Java? They're two completely different programming languages.